# CSS truncation doesn't work

Tags: css

Could you please advice why the price($33000000.33) when it is long jumping to the second line? I need to have a price and "Super Long title" on the same line. Basically, when the price is too big then I need to truncate the "Super Long title" like "Super Lon..." for example and still have both on the same line.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="item-description group">
  <a href="/pro/test-item-with-variations">
    <p class="title truncate-text" title="">Test Item with variationsktvy9i</p>
  </a>
  <p class="shop truncate-text" title="">
    <a href="/pro">Super long title</a>
  </p>
  <a href="/pro/test-item-with-variations">
    <p class="price">$33000000.33</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jaewa.png)

```
.item-description {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: white;
    display: block;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #66c6c3;
    background-color: transparent;
}
p.shop {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.shop {
    color: #5d6d6d;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.truncate-text {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
p {
    display: block;
}
p.shop a {
    color: #5d6d6d;
}
p.price {
    font-size: 16px;
}
.price {
    color: #62c6c4;
    font-weight: 600;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these rulesets directly on the element with the long text:

```
.ellipse {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*vertical-align: middle;*//* for content in a table-cell*/
  width: 100%;
}
```

- Removed all floats,
- Placed all anchors inside the paragraphs,
- Made all paragraphs `display: inline-block`,
- Made all anchors `display: block`

**Note:** All added `outline`s and `background-color`s are to show where the edge of elements exist and where the text is clipped. It's basically a consistent clip on the same line (no wrapping) at the right edge of the element.

**Snippet**

```css
a {
  width: 49%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #66c6c3;
}
p {
  width: 49%;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
div {
  outline: 2px dashed #e3e;
}
.ellipse {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  /* for content in a table-cell*/
  width: 100%;
}
.item-description {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.shop {
  color: #5d6d6d;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 49%;

}
.shop a {
  color: #5d6d6d;
}
.price {
  color: #62c6c4;
  font-size: 16px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="item-description group">
  <p class="title" title="">
  <a href="/pro/test-item-with-variations" class="ellipse">
    Test Item with variationsktvy9i&((79777788uhgfrtrfghuooooooogybvtvtuiuy3463%^&8*Upl[lk;klhguifdttftuuuuuuuuuuuuuyvtfcjhgfds</a>
  </p><br/>
  <p class="shop" title="">
    <a class="ellipse" href="/pro">Super long titlexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</a>
  </p>
  <p class="price" title="">
    <a href="/pro/test-item-with-variations" class="ellipse">$3300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.33</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments, my problem is solved.

```css
.item-description {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: white;
    display: block;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #66c6c3;
    background-color: transparent;
}
p.shop {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.shop {
    color: #5d6d6d;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 10%;
}
.truncate-text {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
p.shop a {
    color: #5d6d6d;
}
p.price {
    font-size: 16px;
}
.price {
    color: #62c6c4;
    font-weight: 600;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:190.5px;">
<div class="item-description group">
  <a href="/pro/test-item-with-variations">
    <p class="title truncate-text" title="">Test Item with variationsktvy9i</p>
  </a>
  <div style="height:20px;">
  <a href="/pro/test-item-with-variations">
    <span class="price">$33000000.33</span>
  </a>
  <p class="shop truncate-text" title="">
    <a href="/pro">Super long title</a>
  </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```